# What is the difference between `r`n and `n for line breaks in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, newline, line-breaks

I know that there are different line-break codes in windows and unix. But in Powershell, both `` `r`n `` and `` `n `` work for a line break.
Is there an automatic conversion from `` `n `` to `` `r`n `` and why do you have to use quotes instead of backslashes?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-new-lines-with-powershell/
And an explanation for carriage return:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091524/what-are-carriage-return-linefeed-and-form-feed

Comment: You can backslash the backquote for stackoverflow.

Comment: @mklement0 It works in posts too, in the case where there's 2 backquotes.

Comment: @js2010 Regarding the original form of your comment: \\` works for _unstyled_ use of a \` character in posts, but not if you want to use one as part of an inline code snippet, which is what Siminho tried to do. And, yes, using _two_ enclosing backticks is the solution to the latter, as already shown in the updated question, and as previously mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking scripts, PowerShell will interpret both the `\n` and `\r\n` end-of-line (EOL) sequence equally when parsing.  The `\r\n` EOL is mostly a Windows artifact of the past, and most of the modern (ca. 2018) Windows apps released will interpret them the same.

Those are not quotes, but *grave accents* or *backticks* (the tilde key on most keyboards) and they are the designated string escape character in PowerShell.

One thing that does impact parsing of a *Windows* PowerShell script is the use of a Byte Order Mark (BOM).  This is the only way to get the PowerShell interpreter to see unicode (such as emojis) in your code; that is, by using UTF8-BOM.

Comment: Note that it's not just PowerShell source-code files (such as scripts) that accept either newline sequence (or even a mix in a single file): all built-in text-file-reading cmdlets do, notably `Get-Content`.
While it is increasingly common that applications can _read_ files with either sequence, they typically _write_ with the _platform-native_ sequence (notably, PowerShell and the .NET APIs), which is CRLF on Windows, and won't go away anytime soon, if ever.
As such, it isn't an artifact of the past.

Comment: To be more specific about the BOM requirement for correct decoding of UTF-8: It is only _Windows PowerShell_ (the Windows-only edition with versions up to 5.1)  that requires the BOM, not PowerShell [Core] (the cross-platform edition with versions starting at 6), which consistently defaults to (BOM-less) UTF-8.

Comment: I did specify that part about Windows PowerShell, but good callout on newline parsing @mklement0

Comment: Thanks; yes, I just wanted to mention the Windows PowerShell / PowerShell [Core] edition dichotomy more explicitly, especially since PowerShell [Core] will become increasingly important over time. The upshot is: to write cross-edition scripts / modules, save your source-code files as UTF-8 _with BOM_.

Answer (score 6):

- **On *input*, PowerShell accepts `` `r`n `` (Windows-style) and `` `n `` (Unix-style) and  [newlines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) *interchangeably***, irrespective of the platform (OS) it runs on; this applies both to reading PowerShell source-code files (such as `*.ps1` scripts) and to all built-in cmdlets that read text, notably [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content).

  - `` `n `` is LF, the LINE FEED, [`U+000A`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a) character, used *by itself* as a newline on *Unix-like platforms*.
  - `` `r`n `` is CRLF, the newline *sequence* composed of a CARRIAGE RETURN ([`U+000D`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d)) character immediately followed by an LF, used as a newline on *Windows*.
  - `` ` `` is used above, because **it is `` ` ``,  the *backtick*** (formally known as GRAVE ACCENT, [`U+0060`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/60)) **that serves as the [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) in PowerShel**l, unlike in many other languages, where it is `\` (for instance, `` `n `` in PowerShell corresponds to `\n` in C# and JavaScript, and `` `r`n `` to `\r\n`.

    - `` ` `` serves as the escape character in PowerShell:

      - inside [expandable strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-and-double-quoted-strings) (`"..."`; but *not* inside `'...'`, whose content is used *verbatim*) no
      - in *unquoted* arguments passed to commands, where its primary purpose is to escape *metacharacters* (characters such as `;` that have syntactic function), i.e. to use them *verbatim*; e.g., `` Write-Host a`;b ``)
      - See the conceptual [about_Special_Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) help topic for more information and the **list of supported escape sequences**.
    - Note that in *regex* contexts (such as via the `-match` and `-replace` operators), `\`-based escape sequences (such as `\n`) can still come into play, namely when these escape sequences are interpreted by the *.NET regular-expression engine* rather than by PowerShell itself (e.g. `` "a`nb" -replace '\n' `` yields `'ab'`); see the conceptual [about_Regular_Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) help topic.
- **On *output*, PowerShell uses the *platform-native* newline sequence: `` `r`n `` on Windows, `` `n `` on Unix-like platforms.**

  - This applies to use of *text-file-creating cmdlets*, which comprise:

    - Cmdlets for *plain-text* file creation: `Set-Content` and `Out-File` / redirection operator `>`.
    - Cmdlets that create *structured text* files, such as `Export-Csv`.
  - As an aside:

    - In *PowerShell [Core] 6+*, the consistently used *character encoding* when text files are created (and read) is [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) *without* a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte%20order%20mark).
    - By contrast, in *Windows PowerShell* (PowerShell versions up to 5.1), the default encodings vary by cmdlet, and choosing UTF-8 via the `-Encoding` parameter of an output cmdlet invariably creates a file *with* a BOM.
    - For more information about (default) character encodings in Windows PowerShell vs. PowerShell [Core], see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375).

---

As for **your specific questions**:

> Is there an **automatic conversion** from `` `n `` to `` `r`n ``?

In a sense, yes:

**Saving to a file with a text-file-creating cmdlet implicitly uses the *platform-native* newline sequence**, as discussed above.

Therefore, reading a file with `Get-Content` (which reads the file *line by line* by default) and saving these lines back to a file with `Set-Content` will effectively result in conversion of the original newlines to the platform-native newlines, if the original ones are from the respective other world.

Note that, **separately, the character encoding may change**, because once strings are read *into memory*, information about the input file's character encoding is lost, and text-file-creating cmdlets such as `Set-Content` apply their *default* encoding on output - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375) for background information.

**A targeted conversion to a *specific* newline style, irrespective of what platform you're running on**, requires more work.

- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48919146/45375).

> **why do you have to use backticks (`` ` ``)** instead of backslashes (`\`)?

**`\` as the escape character would have been a poor choice for PowerShell, because `\` is used in *file paths***, given that `\` serves as the (primary) *file-system path separator* on Windows, and given that passing file paths as arguments is a very common use case in shells.

Having to `\`-escape these path separators to disambiguate them from `\` as the escape character (e.g, `"C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell"` instead of `"C:\Program Files\PowerShell"`) would have been an undue burden (this escaping is annoying enough in programming languages such as C# and JavaScript, though recent versions now offer alternative syntax forms where the escaping isn't needed).

Therefore, **PowerShell needed a different escape character, and settled on `` ` ``**, because:

- it is rare in *literal* use; that is, you'll rarely have to escape `` ` `` itself - as ``` `` ``` - in order to use it *verbatim*.
- at least on English keyboards, it is easy to type.

**Other shells**:

- `cmd.exe` too had to choose a different escape character, and chose `^`, the *caret* (formally known as CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT, [`U+005E`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/5e)).
- POSIX-like shells such as Bash never faced this problem, because it is `/`, not `\`, that serves as the separator in Unix file-system paths; therefore, these shells use `\` as the escape character, like most programming languages.

Comment: Great answer, tons of useful information ⭐

Comment: I'm glad to hear it is useful, @Prid, and I appreciate the nice feedback.

Answer (score 0):

When the file is read into an array of strings with get-content (without -raw), there's no line endings at all.  Then out-file (">") or set-content will put the line endings in depending on the operating system.  Mac OS used to be `r only, but it's just like unix now, `n.

Here's a file in osx with just `n (0x0A):

```
format-hex file


   Label: /Users/js/foo/file

          Offset Bytes                                           Ascii
                 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
          ------ ----------------------------------------------- -----
0000000000000000 61 62 63 0A 61 62 63 0A                         abc�abc�
```

I have a post about converting formats over here:  [Unix newlines to windows newlines (on Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724083/unix-newlines-to-windows-newlines-on-windows/52593215#52593215)