# remove CR line terminators

Tags: shell, unix, newline, dos

Firstly I would say that I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313178/whats-the-best-way-of-doing-dos2unix-on-a-500k-line-file-in-windows) however I still have problems for the `CR line terminators`.

There is a file called `build_test.sh`, I edited in `leafpad` and it can be displayed right in `Vim`:

```
cp ~/moonbox/llvm-2.9/lib/Transforms/MY_TOOL/$1 test.cpp 
cd ~/moonbox/llvm-obj/tools/TEST_TOOL/
make
make install
cd -
```

However:

1. Using `cat build_test.sh` it outputs *nothing*.
2. Using `more build_test.sh` it outputs:`cd - install/llvm-obj/tools/TEST_TOOL/Y_TOOL/$1 test.cpp`
3. Using `less build_test.sh` it outputs: `cp ~/moonbox/llvm-2.9/lib/Transforms/MY_TOOL/$1 test.cpp^Mcd ~/moonbox/llvm-obj/tools/TEST_TOOL/^Mmake^Mmake install^Mcd -`

The result of `file build_test.sh` is:

```
build_test.sh: ASCII text, with CR line terminators
```

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313178/whats-the-best-way-of-doing-dos2unix-on-a-500k-line-file-in-windows/313196#313196), the `^M` no longer exists however there is no more line break :-(
The result of `file build_test_no_cr.sh` is now:

```
build_test_nocr.sh: ASCII text, with no line terminators
```

The solution can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080306/remove-cr-line-terminators/14080764#14080764).

**However I still would like why `cat` displays nothing and `more` displays so odd result. In addition why `dos2unix` and `set fileformat=unix` in Vim fails** for this case.

ps: I guess that maybe my editor(*Vim* or *leafpad*?) generates only `\r` rather `\n` for the newline. How can it be so?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simple `\r` terminators for newlines are "old Mac" line terminators, it is strange that an editor in 2012+ even generates files with such line terminators... Anyway, you can use the `mac2unix` command, which is part of the `dos2unix` distribution:

```
# Edits thefile inline
mac2unix thefile
# Takes origfile as an input, outputs to dstfile
mac2unix -n origfile dstfile
```

This command will not munge files which have already expected line terminators, which is a bonus. And the reverse (`unix2mac`) also exists.

Note that `mac2unix` is the same as `dos2unix -c mac`.

Comment: That is most bizarre, this command has always worked for me. Care to tell how you attempt to use it?

Comment: The `build_test.sh` is edited firstly using `leafpad`(not from Windows or dos OS). I just use `dos2unix build_test.sh build_test_nocr.sh` and the `file build_test_nocr.sh` tells me that `build_test_nocr.sh: ASCII text, with CR line terminators`

Comment: You said this is "not from Windows or dos OS" -- what OS is that then?

Comment: OK, I made a very gross error in the syntax, in fact dos2unix modifies the file in place... Try and see the edited post

Comment: You mean `dos2unix build_test.sh`? No effect. I updated the question and hope you can explain :->

Comment: Hmm, it looks like `\r`-only line terminators are old Mac style terminators. Can you try `mac2unix` instead?

Comment: Yes, it works;thanks! BTW, would you please tell me about the odd result of `cat`,`more` or some more details, please?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but I _think_ this has to do with the way the terminal itself treats newlines. As I see it, terminals will recognize a `\n` character as a newline and do the appropriate action on the display, whereas they will display `\r` as `^M`. Terminals (well, ttys) are a complicated matter...

Answer (score 12):

Also, if you work with vim, you can enforce UNIX line endings by executing

```
:set fileformat=unix
:w
```

or just add

```
set fileformat=unix
```

to your .vimrc file

Comment: nice one. but this will done for all files manually.

Answer (score 6):

I finally figured out that I could use this command:

```
tr '^M' '\n' <build_test.sh >build_test_nocr.sh
```

where `^M` is added by pressing `Ctrl+v` and `Enter` keys.Alternately, this has the same effect:

```
tr '\r' '\n' <build_test.sh >build_test_nocr.sh
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the CTRL-V do to the terminal?

Comment: @ddrjm it usually indicates "verbatim insert", see https://superuser.com/a/421468/88312