# Could not open obj file

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

so I'm working on a project that pulls zip files which include .obj files, unzips them and displays them using ARkit. At the moment I've been able to unzip and save the file in my documents directory as a .obj file and it says the file exists, but when I try to convert it into a scn it says "Could not open OBJ file". Here is my code and I'm trying to figure out where I went wrong. The file size is 314 KB so I know that's not the issue and the obj file isn't corrupted because I can download it to my computer and open it up.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var testData: Store?
var logoImage: UIImage?
var urlForObject: String?
var tempDirectoryString: String?
var tempDirectoryURL: URL?
var testModelData: Data?
var testData2: Data?
var testData3: Models?
var tempDocumentsURL: URL?


@IBOutlet weak var logoImageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.clearCowZipFolder()
    self.clearCowFolder()

    self.requestZipFile(){ response in
        self.testData2 = response
        do{
            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response, options: [])

            if let array = json as? [String] {
                if let firstObject = array.first {
                    //print(firstObject)
                }

                for object in array {
                    // access all objects in array
                }

                for case let string as String in array {
                    // access only string values in array
                }
            }

        }catch{
            print("errorrrr")
        }
    }
    self.tempDocumentsURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first as URL!
    let destinationFileUrl = self.tempDocumentsURL!.appendingPathComponent("Man.zip")
    var destPath = self.tempDocumentsURL!.appendingPathComponent("Man")

    //Create URL to the source file you want to download
    let fileURL = URL(string: "http://markitapi.com/stores/TestStore/models/Man")

    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)

    let request = URLRequest(url:fileURL!)

    let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response3, error) in
        if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {
            // Success
            if let statusCode = (response3 as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                print("Successfully downloaded. Status code: \(statusCode)")

                do {
                    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: destinationFileUrl)
                } catch (let writeError) {
                    print("Error creating a file \(destinationFileUrl) : \(writeError)")
                }

                do{
                    let unzipDirectory = try Zip.quickUnzipFile(destinationFileUrl) //Unzip
                        print("HHERHERHEHRE")
                        destPath = unzipDirectory
                }catch{
                    print("error while unzipping")
                }

                print("UNZIPPED PATH")
                //print(destPath)

                let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
                let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
                if let pathComponent = url.appendingPathComponent("Man/Man.obj") {
                    let filePath = pathComponent.path
                    //print(filePath)
                    let fileManager = FileManager.default
                    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
                        print("FILE AVAILABLE")
                    } else {
                        print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("FILE PATH NOT AVAILABLE")
                }

                let url2 = (String(describing: destPath) + "Man.obj")
                let url3 = URL(fileURLWithPath: url2)
                print(url3.pathExtension)
                let asset = MDLAsset(url: url3)
                //print(asset)
                let object = asset.object(at: 0)
                let node = SCNNode(mdlObject: object)
                //print(node)

            }

        } else {
            //print("Error took place while downloading a file. Error description: %@", error?.localizedDescription);
        }
    }
    task.resume()

}

func clearCowZipFolder() {
    let fileNameToDelete = "Man.zip"
    var filePath = ""

    // Fine documents directory on device
    let dirs : [String] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.allDomainsMask, true)

    if dirs.count > 0 {
        let dir = dirs[0] //documents directory
        filePath = dir.appendingFormat("/" + fileNameToDelete)
        //print("Local path = \(filePath)")

    } else {
        print("Could not find local directory to store file")
        return
    }


    do {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        // Check if file exists
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
            // Delete file
            try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: filePath)
        } else {
            print("File does not exist")
        }

    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("An error took place: \(error)")
    }
}

func clearCowFolder() {
    let fileNameToDelete = "Man"
    var filePath = ""

    // Fine documents directory on device
    let dirs : [String] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.allDomainsMask, true)

    if dirs.count > 0 {
        let dir = dirs[0] //documents directory
        filePath = dir.appendingFormat("/" + fileNameToDelete)
        //print("Local path = \(filePath)")

    } else {
        print("Could not find local directory to store file")
        return
    }


    do {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        // Check if file exists
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
            // Delete file
            try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: filePath)
        } else {
            print("File does not exist")
        }

    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("An error took place: \(error)")
    }
}

func requestZipFile(success successBlock: @escaping (Data) -> Void){
    Alamofire.request("http://markitapi.com/stores/TestStore/models").responseJSON { (response) in
        do{
            if(response.result.isSuccess){
                successBlock(response.data!)
            }
        }catch{
            print("error")
        }
        }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

The first part of the code checks to see if the file is available and it does print that statement, so I know the file is there.

Comment: See my answer on the following question for a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48154432/error-obj-file-has-no-faces

Comment: @Xartec I'm getting the correct line from the terminal:
Cow.obj: ASCII text

Comment: Edit: Just uploaded all my code